# AJAX form not submitting that gives error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have my AJAX code here

```
$("#add-student").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    formData = $("#student-form").serialize(); 
    if (cleanFormInput()) {
        sendTheInfo(formData);
    } else { 
        shakeForm();
    }
});

function sendTheInfo(formData) { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../classes/ajax/postNewStudent.php",
        data: formData, 
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                alert( "page not found" );
            }
        },
        success: function(formData) { 
            console.log("New student submitted:\n" + formData);
        //clearForms();
        },
        error: function(result, sts, err) { 
            console.warn("Connection error:\n" + err + " : " + sts);
            console.log(result);
            shakeForm();
        },
        complete: function() { 
            console.log("Everything complete");
        }
    });
}
```

Always without fail outputs this error: 
**Connection error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input : parsererror**

But still gives the complete message: **Everything complete**

**Update, PHP code here:**

```
    require '../../core/init.php';
    require '../../classes/Config.php';

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        $id = $_POST["sid"]; 
        $first = $_POST["first"];
        $last = $_POST["last"]; 
        $fav = "0";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `first`, `last`, `active`) VALUES ('{$id}', '{$first}', '{$last}', '{$fav}')";

        $link = mysql_connect(Config::get('mysql/host'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password')) or die("could not connect");;
        mysql_select_db(Config::get('mysql/db'), $link);

        $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

        if ($result) {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $student_data = $id . $first . $last . $fav;
            echo json_encode($student_data);
        }
    }
```

I'm a bit confused, am I doing my ajax set up wrong? Or is it something else in by backend code wrong? I'm using MySQL and jQuery 2.0.3

Updated code here: [here](http://confirmation.joeygallegos.com/add-student/)

Comment: What kind of response is the server script returning? JSON?

Comment: Try to check your server-side.

Comment: You seem to have two semicolons at the end of the `$link = mysql_connect...` line. Try removing the duplicate?

Comment: @Serlite PHP ignores empty statements like that.

Comment: The error means the response from the server is empty. This implies that the `INSERT` is failing, so `if($result)` fails and you're not echoing the JSON.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Edit: Use `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` as per Barmar's comment.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, whoops! Just read about that, guess I haven't used PHP enough to be familiar with it.

Comment: Add `or die(mysql_error())` to the `mysql_query()` line, then check the response in the Network panel of Dev Tools to see the error message.

Comment: @Serlite Did not catch that, updated code and tried again, still the same result.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP error reporting doesn't help with MySQL errors, you have to echo `mysql_error()` explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar It was a thought. I noticed that after and was going to edit my comment in regards to what you posted about `mysql_error()`

Comment: @Barmar I removed the content-type as suggested, and that cleared up my problem, but I attached the mysql "or die" as suggested by serlite, and that is sent through to console.

Comment: And what does it say?

Comment: @Barmar all my code works server side, but not locally using xampp. Would you happen to know why? It works on the server(now) but I have the same code and DB setup on my local machine, any ideas?

Comment: @Barmar if you check console on the server it says it goes through, but locally it doesn't.

Comment: Must be some kind of configuration problem on your local machine. What does the error message say when you run it locally?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I must be super annoying at this point haha. It says:

Connection error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c : parsererror
(returns the object)Object

Comment: What version of php is on your server VS your wamp local set up?  that might be the issue.

Comment: Also, could be your mysql rejecting the object format in the values.  are you using that format on purpose?  have you tried just '$id' instead of '{$id}' ?

Comment: You're not looking in the right place. That's the error coming from jQuery when it tries to parse the JSON response. I want you to go to the Network tab, select the AJAX call to `postNewStudent.php`, go into the Response sub-tab, and look at the response that was sent by the server. That will contain the MySQL error message.

Answer (score 0):

removed my old answer. I don't think it is an ajax/javascript error. it's definitely a PHP error. It's this lines:

```
$student_data = $id . $first . $last . $fav;
echo json_encode($student_data);
```

You $student_data is not an array, it's just a string. You need to pass an array into the `json_encode` function

Comment: Sending the header has the same effect as specifying the `dataType` option.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah you are right.. if not explicitly specified, it just checks the Content type of the header.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at your code. I saw that from the PHP side you are sending a JSON object. but you didn't specified the return **dataType** for the response. Try to add the dataType in the ajax call. Maybe that will solve the problem

```
function sendTheInfo(formData) { 
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "../classes/ajax/postNewStudent.php",
    data: formData, 
    dataType : 'json',
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert( "page not found" );
        }
    },
    success: function(formData) { 
        console.log("New student submitted:\n" + formData);
    //clearForms();
    },
    error: function(result, sts, err) { 
        console.warn("Connection error:\n" + err + " : " + sts);
        console.log(result);
        shakeForm();
    },
    complete: function() { 
        console.log("Everything complete");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a `dataType:` option, jQuery figures it out automatically from the `Content-type` header. Since he's sending `application/json`, it's the same as `dataType: 'json'`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the Ajax COMPLETE method will fire even if the back end does not return a result.

```
complete: function() { 
        console.log("Everything complete");
    }
```

will thus show the log'ed entry every time an ajax call is 'finished executing', even if the submit failed.

I would also suggest NOT having 2 headers or the same declaration (you have one up top, and one in the if(result) call.

In a comment thread, you pointed out that you're working on the server but not locally, And thus that implies you have some pathing issues.   Check your

```
  ../
```

relative path style urls and make sure that you have the same basepoints.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that modern jQuery has deprecated complete.    "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."